# How to deny access to resources based on X-forwarded-for headers

Tags: nginx

I am trying to restrict access to resources behind Nginx based on client IP passed in X-forwarded-for headers. Nginx is running in a container on a Kubernetes Cluster on Google Cloud Platform and real client ips are passed in x-forwarded-for header only

So far I've managed to do it for a single IP with the following code:

```
set $allow false;
if ($http_x_forwarded_for ~* 123.233.233.123) {
    set $allow true;
}
if ($http_x_forward_for ~* 10.20.30.40) {
    set $allow false;
}
if ($allow = false) {
    return 403;
}
```

But how can i do that for whole ranges of IPs? Specifying hundreds of IPs by hand doesn't make much sense.

All help is appreciated

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use the RealIP module to honour the value of the `X-Forwarded-For` header. Set `set_real_ip_from` to the IP address of the reverse proxy (the current value of `$remote_addr`).

For example:

```
server {
    ...
    real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;
    set_real_ip_from 10.1.2.3;
    ...
}
```

You should now be able to use `$remote_addr` and `allow`/`deny` directives using the true IP address of the client. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_realip_module.html) for more.

Comment: so I tried the following to no avail, am I confusing it?

        `location / {
            real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;
            set_real_ip_from 10.0.0.0/8;
            real_ip_recursive on;

            allow xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;`

Comment: After looking at Google Load Balancing docs I found the following: `X-Forwarded-For: <unverified IP(s)>, <immediate client IP>, <global forwarding rule external IP>, <proxies running in GCP> (requests only) `
The <immediate client IP> entry is the client that connected directly to the load balancer .

Comment: For this to work, you need to identify the address ranges for `<global forwarding rule external IP>` and `<proxies running in GCP>` and add `set_real_ip_from` statements covering all of them.

Comment: `<global forwarding rule external IP>` is the external ip of my service, there are no other proxies in GCP, on my nginx logs I see requests in the following format `[31/Jul/2017:20:05:46 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 169 "-" "curl/7.54.0" "aaa.aaa.aaa.aaa, bbb.bbb.bbb.bbb, ccc.ccc.ccc.ccc"` where ccc.ccc.ccc.ccc is global forwarding rule, bbb.bbb.bbb.bbb a immediate client ip - matches what I see in whatsmyip.org. Any chance you can advise how to extract that part?

Comment: Ok, now I'm getting confused. You need to `set_real_ip_from` for all of the addresses to the right of the one you want to allow/deny. As indicated in the `real_ip_recursive` section.

Comment: Thanks Richard, It was me confusing things. Got it working finally!

Answer (score 6):

Richard's answer already contained the information on how to best get the real IP address to nginx.

Meanwhile, what comes to the question of specifying IP ranges, you can use http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_geo_module.html.

The `geo` module works like the `map` module, that is, a variable gets assigned values depending on the value of IP address.

An example:

```
geo $allow {
    default 0;
    192.168.168.0/24 1;
}

server {
    real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;
    set_real_ip_from 10.1.2.3;

    if ($allow = 0) {
        return 403;
    }
}
```

Here we assign the `geo` map, where the default value for `$allow` is 0. If the IP address is in subnet `192.168.168.0/24`, then `$allow` will get value 1, and the request is allowed.

You can have as many lines in the `geo` block as you need to define your IP ranges.

Comment: Thank you! that seems to work really well, last one thing I'm facing is that client_ip from X-forwarded-for. At the moment, from 3 ip addresses that are passed the last one is used. I have added `real_ip_recursive on;` below `set_real_ip_from` but it hasn't made any difference

Comment: Do you mean your `X-Forwarded-For` header has three separate addresses, that is, the request comes via multiple proxies? Do you have any other header there you can use, which contains only the client IP?

Comment: Every proxy in the chain will append it's IP address to the `X-Forwarded-For` header. In addition to adding `real_ip_recursive on` you also need to add `set_real_ip_from` directives for each trusted server IP address in your proxy chain. Nginx will then work through each of these directives and return the client IP as the first value it hits in the `X-Forwarded-For` header which does not match any of your specified `set_real_ip_from` values

Comment: FWIW, this combination did not work for me with AWS ALB. What did work was using the proxy directive inside the geo block, with the same ip as set_real_ip - https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_geo_module.html

Answer (score 4):

Got these working for me.

```
geo $remote_addr $giveaccess {
      proxy 172.0.0.0/8; <-- Private IP range here
      default 0;
      11.22.33.44 1; <-- Allowed IP here
    }


server{
##
    location ^~ /secure_url_here {
        if ($giveaccess = 0){
          return 403; 
        }
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args; <-- Add this line specific for your CMS, if required.
    }
```

Ref: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_geo_module.html